# Why moment / i18 code is downloaded to client if using only in server in Next.js SSG

Tags: reactjs, next.js, momentjs, server-side-rendering, i18next

We uses moment and i18 for translation, but only on server side. When generating HTML. Why it is downloaded to client? Why it uses brandwith and increase "Time to Interactive"?

Some code

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import {
  getDateString,
  getFormattedTimeInterval,
  countTotalBookings,
} from "../../Utility/Utility";
import { MainTableProps, EventTypeEnum, PricingOptionType } from "../../Types";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import useWindowSize from "../../Utility/UseWindowSize";
import i18n from "i18next";
import accounting from "accounting-js";
import moment from "moment";
```

```js
function MainTable(props: MainTableProps) {
  const {
    showOnlyStartEndTime,
    eventTimes,
    passes,
    pricingOptions,
    ratingAvg,
    minParticipants,
    maxParticipants,
  } = props.buyTicketData;
  const { t } = useTranslation("buyTicket");
```

```js
  return (
    ...

                     <span>
                        {!props.dateRange[0].startDate ||
                        !props.dateRange[0].endDate
                          ? t("cdr34")
                          : moment(props.dateRange[0].startDate).format(
                              "YYYY.MM.DD"
                            ) +
                            " - " +
                            moment(props.dateRange[0].endDate).format(
                              "YYYY.MM.DD"
                            )}
                      </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to do the calculation on serverside so you should use the function inside getServerSideProps instead of return block of your component

Comment: thanks, it helped a lot, do you know where I find relating info in docs?

Comment: welcome happy that it helped, @János here:  https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering more information